# Is it more stressful for server to write in a big LOG file than in a smaller one?

Tags: linux, optimization, server, logfile

I started optimizing a linux server which holds several cPanel accounts. The first step is to remove/delete unused accounts/files so we can have more disk space. As i was researching I found an account which had a log of 2GB and that made me think and create the current question.

Is it more stressful for server to write a single line on a log file of 2GB than a smaller one? For example a 10MB file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No it is not more stressful for the server to write to a big log file**

Most (if not all) logging services open the log file in append mode (which is the same as write mode, but writes data to the end of the file, instead of the beginning).

By doing this, the contents of the log file is not loaded into memory - instead the log entry is merely appended to the log file.